# I would like to add a tooltip to the glyphicon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3, tooltip

```
Rails 4.1
Bootstrap 3
```

This is the code for the view:

```
<td>
  <%= link_to my_model, class: 'btn btn-info' do %>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
  <% end %>
</td>
```

I would like to add a tooltip when the mouse hovers over the button to display something like "View Agent Data". I found some help on how to do this with bootstrap, but not when using a glyphcon. Any ideas?

## Solution:

In the view:

```
<%= link_to my_model, class: 'btn btn-info',  title: 'View Agent Data', 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip', 'data-placement' => 'right' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
<% end %>
```

In application.js:

```
$(document).on("ready page:change", function() {
  $('.btn-info').tooltip();
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the necessary data attributes in the 'link_to' helper:

```
<%= link_to my_model, class: 'btn btn-info',  title: 'View Agent Data', 'data-toggle' => 'tooltip', 'data-placement' => 'right' do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Based on your tip, I added some .JS to my application.js, and it works. See my edits